# Warning messages in model with caret

Tags: r, caret

I am trying to generate a model via `caret` package and I get some warnings which I cannot explain. Just to make my post reproductive I use as data frame the `iris` set.

```
data(iris)
df=iris[,1:4]
con = trainControl(method="cv", number=3)
for_train = createDataPartition(df$Sepal.Length, p=.66, list=FALSE) 
train=df[for_train,] 
test=df[-for_train,] 
model = train(Sepal.Length ~., data = train, method = "ANFIS", trControl = con)
```

with the above code I get 7 Warnings :

```
In validate.params(object, newdata) :
  There are your newdata which are out of the specified range
```

So,

What exactly are  the warning messages?

Are these warnings a sign that I did not built my model correctly?

**EDIT**

While I was waiting for a help about the warnings I tried to generate the model without the `caret` package, with the use of the `frbs`:

```
df=iris[,1:4]
train <- df[1 : 100, ]
test <- df[101 : 150, 1 : 3]
real.val <- matrix(df[101 : 150, 4], ncol = 1)

my_range<-apply(train,2,range)

method.type <- "ANFIS"
control <- list(num.labels = 3, max.iter = 10, step.size = 0.01, type.tnorm = "MIN", type.snorm = "MAX", type.implication.func = "ZADEH", name = "iris")

my_object <- frbs.learn(train, my_range, method.type, control)
test_pr <- predict(my_object, test)
```

But still I get the same warnings and the `test_pr` is characterized by only only value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These warnings are not from the caret package, but come from the frbs. If range.data is not given, it is calculated on the data coming into frbs.learn. For ANSI it is calculated as follows:

```
 dt.min <- matrix(do.call(pmin, lapply(1:nrow(data.train), 
        function(i) data.train[i, ])), nrow = 1)
 dt.max <- matrix(do.call(pmax, lapply(1:nrow(data.train), 
        function(i) data.train[i, ])), nrow = 1)

 range.data <- rbind(dt.min, dt.max)
```

With the 3 fold cv, you can have data points which fall outside dt.min / dt.max. That is the error / warning you get.

**Edit:**
Looking into the documentation of [fbrs](http://dicits.ugr.es/software/FRBS/index.php), they mention the following:

> Range of data could be defined or omitted. If it is omitted, frbswill
>   calculate minimum and maximum of training data as the range. But, we
>   recommend this parameter should be defined to avoid some data out of
>   range, especially when performing predicting phase.

Looking into the examples and running a few tests, the range should be defined based on the full input data, not on the training data.

For the iris data set: `range_data_input <- matrix(apply(iris[, 1:4], 2, range), nrow = 2)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my question and as you can see the warning (you are right, is associated with the frbs) is still here despite the fact that I used the range.

Comment: @geo_dd, See edit in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! The range of the entire data set was the key.

Comment: but in caret there is no range option so how can we use in caret plz help